# Is there a TOTP variant that does not require the user to type in a code?

Tags: mobile, multi-factor, one-time-password

We're considering a 2 factor TOTP solution on a mobile phone. However, it would be much easier for the user to somehow send the OTP to the server by pushing a button, rather than manually typing in a code. Of course this would require an internet connection, but it would make it a much more user friendly solution. 
Is there such a solution? And does it have any negative security implications? Or are we better of using some sort of push-based solution like [Duo push](https://www.duosecurity.com/duo-push)?

Comment: Im not understanding correctly, what is the difference between what you want to do and Duo push?